# get list in plain text using regex

Tags: php, regex, text-processing, plaintext

I want to get all the list items in a plain text (.txt file) using regex. For example in:

```
Books must I read this week before Saturday:
1. Geography
2. Math
3. Biology
The priority book is book 2. This book is borrowed by John.
```

I use `preg_match_all` as follows

```
$pattern = "/^[0-9]\.(.*)\n/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $filehandler, $matches);
```

I expect the following result:

```
1. Geography
2. Math
3. Biology
```

The string `2. This book is borrowed by John.` should not be matched in `$matches`. But I get nothing from that pattern. Does anyone know what pattern I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
$list = 'Books must I read this week before Saturday:
1. Geography
  2. Math
        3. Biology
The priority book is book 2. This book is borrowed by John.';

preg_match_all('/\n[\s\t]*(\d+\..*)/', $list, $bullets);

var_dump($bullets);
```

Comment: `\s` matches `[\r\n\t\f\v ]` so you can rewrite your expression to drop the character class into `\s*`

Comment: @JoeFrambach there are virtually endless _won't work_ cases for all solutions but thanks for adding useful information to the page :)

Comment: :) it's fine since in my work that case will be found, may be I should make the question more general. But it's OK. Thanks to you all. I will do the rest, and share the stack I find here happily (I think why this site's name is "stackoverflow")

Answer (score 0):

the most efficient way is to use the multiline mode :

```
preg_match_all('/^[0-9]+\. .*$/m', $list, $matches);
$result = $matches[0];
```

Comment: I pasted this pattern but I didn't get some matches.

Comment: What's strange! Have you change $list to $filehandler or your string name, cause the pattern is tested and work with the example you give?

Comment: Yes, I have. I also tried another working pattern from regex tools in the net, but they didn't work in my notebook. May be something wrong in my PHP setting or something. All pattern with `^` and `/m` are fail to match. Sorry, may be this problem out of topic.

Comment: I made a simple test: `$string = "abc\nabc"; preg_match_all("/^a.*/m", $string, $matches); var_dump($matches);`. It's work since it gives `array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "abc" [1]=> string(3) "abc" } }`. Maybe I should try it again.